# Why the file describer redirected changes after grep command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

```
$exec 3<input.txt
$sleep 60 >&3 &
[1] 32524
$ cd/proc/32534/fd 
$ ls -l
lrwx------. 1 zhangchen zhangchen 64 Sep 24 18:29 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------. 1 zhangchen zhangchen 64 Sep 24 18:29 1 -> /home/zhangchen/input.txt
lrwx------. 1 zhangchen zhangchen 64 Sep 24 18:29 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------. 1 zhangchen zhangchen 64 Sep 24 18:29 3 -> /home/zhangchen/input.txt

$grep test_word <&3
test_word
$grep test_word <&3
[nothing output]
```

Isn't grep search the file using describer 1, why did grep change the file describer 3?

Comment: `sleep 60 >&3 &` doesn't change anything meaningful. The `>&3` is short for `1>&3`, which is why you see FD 3 copied to FD 1 for the `sleep` process, but that doesn't have anything to do with why your second grep doesn't work.

Comment: (Similarly, `<&3` is short for `0<&3`, so if you looked at the FD table for both `grep`s, you'd see FD 3 copied to FD 0 for those processes).

Comment: ...and to be clear, grep searches content from _stdin_, FD 0; it doesn't search FD 1 -- 1 is stdout, where it writes its output.

Comment: ...if you're asking why FD 3 is still set on the sleep command after the `>&3`, that's because you didn't anything to unset it; `>&3` is a _copy_ from 3 to 1, not a _move_ from 3 to 1; but that has nothing to do with grep.

Comment: (Also, keep in mind that it's copying a _pointer_, so both 3 and 1 point to the same kernel object; this is why reading from FD 0 after `<&3` is run also changes the location within the file for the FD 3 descriptor, which is pointed at the same handle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *not* changing which file is open on FD 3, or what the contents of that file are. What changes is *where in the file you're at*.

You're opening `input.txt` once.

Before you run grep, the file pointer is at the front of the file.

After you run grep, the file pointer is at the end of the file.

It still points to the same file, but you're not at the front of it anymore, so there's no content left to read if the program you're running doesn't use `seek()` to rewind to the front.

---

You *can* rewind to the front, if you run a program that does so:

```
# Define a "rewind" function that uses Python
rewind() {
  python -c 'import os, sys; os.lseek(int(sys.argv[1]), 0, os.SEEK_SET)' "$@"
}

# Create our input file
echo 'test_word' >input.txt

# Redirect from the input file
exec 3<input.txt

# Read from the input file once
grep test_word <&3

# Rewind the input file back to the beginning
rewind 3

# _Now_ we can read from the input file a second time
grep test_word <&3
```

Comment: why can the grep change FD3 from the front of the file to the end, I think the grep uses its FD0(stdin) to search, but not its FD3, maybe I get anything wrong？

Comment: Thank you for your patience and thoughtful response to my questions

Comment: You are right: grep uses FD 0 for input when no explicit filenames have been provided (or when it's given an explicit filename of `-`); however, in a context where `<&3` has been run, FD 0 is a copy of FD 3, so they point to the same structure in the kernel -- it's that structure where the location within the file is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous: You provide some commands and their output followed by a question, expecting readers to understand your intent; I suggest you'll get more helpful answers if you spend more time writing your question carefully. That said, if I do understand your question correctly, grep is using file descriptor 3 because you explicitly redirected standard input with `<&3`.

Comment: This does not explain why grep only emits output once (which is clearly what the OP intended to ask about).